# funky disappearing Mailchimp subscribe button

Tags: html, wordpress, mailchimp

I embedded a M/C subscribe form in my WP site http://southcumberlandcommunityfund.org/dev/ (Vantage theme, Page Builder plugin). As you can see, the 'sign up now' button fades to nothing. I've changed colors in the html with no difference.

I'd like a solid, visible color (such as the grey whose html # I pasted into the code).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's coming from line 345 of your stylesheet.

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #dfdfdf, #ffffff);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #dfdfdf 0%, #ffffff 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #dfdfdf);
```

This is the selectors:

```
button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"]
```

You can fix this by adding `background-image: none;` in the mailchimp style.